# Checking abstract method behavior (the contract) with assertions in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class, assert, abstract-methods

I want the abstract method to be implemented to keep some contract
e.g.

I have a `Cells` abstract class which is a wrapper around `Cell[]`, `Cells` abstract class has abstract protected method `_initCells`, and I declared `initCells` **final** and **public** method that uses assertions to check if in the `Cell[]` from `_initCells` method output doesn't contain **duplicates** and **out-of-bounds** cells regardless of whether it is chess cells or checker cells.

But assertions are disabled by default and if another package wants to create sub-classes of `Cells` the programmer can ignore the contract by not enabling the assertions.

and what if I have a interface instead of abstract class, how can I enforce a contract?

So far I decided to print a message in System.err and call System.exit from initCells method.

Comment: In your current scheme of things, you really cannot help if a sub-class does not adhere to the principle. Interface will also not help. If you post your code, it would be clearer if there are design alternatives.

Comment: @Ironluca I don't have a complete code for an application with some kind of architecture, I just assumed a general situation and wanted to know the general solution

Comment: How do you plan on writing these assertions? Do you have a specific subclass you want to verify? Or do you want to somehow verify for all subclasses? The later seems impossible if you don't have an actual subclass to use.

Comment: Whether this is good practice is opinion-based... but I'd say if people don't bother to read your Javadoc on how to use the class, they'll probably also break it in other creative ways. Or maybe your classes are not very intuitive to use? I guess it depends on your target audience how much you want to check. But it could get complicated, and you assume that you know what *all* derived classes must do, which may or may not be the case. People can still catch and ignore the exception from `initCells`. If you call `System.exit` I'd not use your library. This is utterly unacceptable for a library.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just was asserting the output of abstract method in non-abstract method of abstract class

Comment: @Robert you are right, I won't use System.exit(), I will throw RuntimeException instead of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertions are disabled by default, but exceptions aren't. If this precondition is a major footgun or is likely to cause safety or security issues if not followed, then raise [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) or one of its subclasses when you detect nonconformance.

```
public final initCells() {
  _initCells();
  if (containsDuplicates()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cells contain duplicates");
  }
  if (anyCellIsOutOfBounds()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cell is out of bounds");
  }
}
```